# How to open csv and docs in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Normally in a Mac, Ubuntu or regular Windows machine, I can install Chrome with the "Office Editing for Docs, Sheets & Slides"
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj

and open any doc under the sun including CSVs.

How do I do that on the new chromium based Microsoft Edge that's installed through the Windows Store?? I have to use that as Chrome would drain my battery on my "Windows 10 on ARM" laptop.

Things I've tried:
- "Open With", it's a useless list that does not include my default browser! Seriously, WTF
- going to the Program Files/WindowsApps folder... it's really locked down
- Installing the extension... Installed correctly, but it didn't add Edge to the Open With list

Updates: I found some errors in the extension... it looks like Edge doesn't support Chrome Apps at all and this is not a real extension... I think.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't!

The extension will not work in Edg/Cromium Edge... it uses App API's

However, you can try opening random files in Edge by using file URI's such as `file:///C:/Users/`

Suggestion, use Chrome and take the battery penalty. Or, upload to cloud storage and let them deal with it.